# Как перевести char в escape последоватльность.

Tags: gcc, g++, c++, linux

Все что находил, было связано с java и php и сводилось к использованию одной буквы. Как можно изменить последовательность символов на escape последоватльность.
пример:

привет
%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант: [RFC 3986, пункт 2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) + `sprintf("%%%2X", символ)`

Answer (score 0):

В составе libcurl есть такие функции: [curl_easy_escape](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html), [curl_easy_unescape](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_unescape.html).

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать онлайн-преобразователи. Например

http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/encoder/

тысячи их!